# How to parse any article from particular site using beautifulsoup and how to preview the image of that link?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse a news article from a sports website from there html feed, I tried using following code, I am getting 'key error'

code that I tried:

```
def get_cric_info_articles():

    cricinfo_article_link = "http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/story/news.html"

    r = requests.get(cricinfo_article_link)
    cricinfo_article_html = r.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(cricinfo_article_html, "html.parser")
    # print(soup.prettify())

    cric_info_items = soup.find_all("h2",
                                      {"class": "story-title"})

    cricinfo_article_dict = {}

    for div in cric_info_items:
      cricinfo_article_dict[div.find('a')['story-title']] = div.find('a')['href']

    return cricinfo_article_dict
```

error message:

> KeyError: 'story-title'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value you looking for is inside `a` tag

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_cric_info_articles():

    cricinfo_article_link = "http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/story/news.html"

    r = requests.get(cricinfo_article_link)
    cricinfo_article_html = r.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(cricinfo_article_html, "html.parser")
    # print(soup.prettify())

    cric_info_items = soup.find_all("h2",
                                    {"class": "story-title"})
    cricinfo_article_dict = {}

    for div in cric_info_items:
        cricinfo_article_dict[div.find('a').string] = div.find('a')['href']

    return cricinfo_article_dict


print(get_cric_info_articles())
```

Output:

> {'Bell-Drummond leads MCC in curtain-raiser': '/ci/content/story/1135157.html', 'Scotland pick Brad Wheal, Chris Sole for World Cup qualifiers': '/scotland/content/story/1135152.html', 'Newlands working to be water independent': '/southafrica/content/story/1135120.html', 'Scorchers bow out after Hurricanes pile up 210': '/australia/content/story/1135117.html', "'Strong evidence' of corruption in Ajman All Stars League - ICC ": '/ci/content/story/1135108.html', 'Du Plessis 120 powers South Africa to 269': '/south-africa-v-india-2018/content/story/1135099.html', "Plan is to expose India's middle, lower order - Harris": '/australia/content/story/1135091.html', 'Top order, King fire Scorchers into WBBL final': '/australia/content/story/1135084.html', 'Technical change brings prolific run for Mominul': '/bangladesh/content/story/1135077.html', 'Dhananjaya, Mendis lead strong Sri Lanka reply': '/bangladesh/content/story/1135075.html'}

Comment: How can I embed image link along with that, so I can show image of that post when I render?

Comment: I wanted those to be callable link, so whenever I press that link it will take to that respective website page,Nylon Calculus: Game Control and a new take on team metrics': 'https://fansided.com/2018/01/30/nylon-calculus-game-control-score/', like this

Answer (score 1):

`div.find('a')['story-title']` won't give you the story title, since the `<a>` tag doesn't have that attribute. That's the reason you're getting `KeyError`.

Use `.text` for the `<a>` tag as the title is located here: `<a> ... </a>`.

```
for h2 in cric_info_items:
    cricinfo_article_dict[h2.find('a').text] = h2.find('a')['href']

for item in cricinfo_article_dict.items():
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
('Bell-Drummond leads MCC in curtain-raiser', '/ci/content/story/1135157.html')
('Scotland pick Brad Wheal, Chris Sole for World Cup qualifiers', '/scotland/content/story/1135152.html')
('Newlands working to be water independent', '/southafrica/content/story/1135120.html')
('Scorchers bow out after Hurricanes pile up 210', '/australia/content/story/1135117.html')
("'Strong evidence' of corruption in Ajman All Stars League - ICC ", '/ci/content/story/1135108.html')
('Du Plessis 120 powers South Africa to 269', '/south-africa-v-india-2018/content/story/1135099.html')
("Plan is to expose India's middle, lower order - Harris", '/australia/content/story/1135091.html')
('Top order, King fire Scorchers into WBBL final', '/australia/content/story/1135084.html')
('Technical change brings prolific run for Mominul', '/bangladesh/content/story/1135077.html')
('Dhananjaya, Mendis lead strong Sri Lanka reply', '/bangladesh/content/story/1135075.html')
```

Also, calling the same method (here, `h2.find('a')`) multiple times is not a good idea as it will take more time. In this case, it won't show any difference in run time as the `<h2>` tag has only one child - `<a>`. But in other cases where the parent has many children, it is a good idea to save the tag you find in a variable and then use it. Something like this:

```
a = h2.find('a')
cricinfo_article_dict[a.text] = a['href']
```

---

**EDIT:**

To get the title, link, and the image link, you can create a list of dictionaries for individual news items with title, link, image as its items.

Try this:

```
cricinfo_article_list = []

for item in cric_info_items:
    item_dict = {}
    item_title = item.find('h2', {'class': 'story-title'}).find('a')
    item_dict['title'] = item_title.text
    item_dict['link'] = item_title['href']
    item_dict['image'] = item.find('img', {'class': 'img-full'})['src']
    cricinfo_article_list.append(item_dict)

for item in cricinfo_article_list:
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
{'title': 'Bell-Drummond leads MCC in curtain-raiser', 'link': '/ci/content/story/1135157.html', 'image': 'http://p.imgci.com/db/PICTURES/CMS/265700/265759.4.jpg'}
{'title': 'Scotland pick Brad Wheal, Chris Sole for World Cup qualifiers', 'link': '/scotland/content/story/1135152.html', 'image': 'http://p.imgci.com/db/PICTURES/CMS/251500/251571.4.jpg'}
{'title': 'Newlands working to be water independent', 'link': '/southafrica/content/story/1135120.html', 'image': 'http://p.imgci.com/db/PICTURES/CMS/271700/271734.5.jpg'}
{'title': 'Scorchers bow out after Hurricanes pile up 210', 'link': '/australia/content/story/1135117.html', 'image': 'http://p.imgci.com/db/PICTURES/CMS/271700/271769.5.jpg'}
{'title': "'Strong evidence' of corruption in Ajman All Stars League - ICC ", 'link': '/ci/content/story/1135108.html', 'image': 'http://p.imgci.com/db/PICTURES/CMS/263200/263221.4.jpg'}
{'title': 'Du Plessis 120 powers South Africa to 269', 'link': '/south-africa-v-india-2018/content/story/1135099.html', 'image': 'http://p.imgci.com/db/PICTURES/CMS/272700/272763.5.jpg'}
{'title': "Plan is to expose India's middle, lower order - Harris", 'link': '/australia/content/story/1135091.html', 'image': 'http://p.imgci.com/db/PICTURES/CMS/272300/272388.5.jpg'}
{'title': 'Top order, King fire Scorchers into WBBL final', 'link': '/australia/content/story/1135084.html', 'image': 'http://p.imgci.com/db/PICTURES/CMS/272700/272734.5.jpg'}
{'title': 'Technical change brings prolific run for Mominul', 'link': '/bangladesh/content/story/1135077.html', 'image': 'http://p.imgci.com/db/PICTURES/CMS/272700/272718.5.jpg'}
{'title': 'Dhananjaya, Mendis lead strong Sri Lanka reply', 'link': '/bangladesh/content/story/1135075.html', 'image': 'http://p.imgci.com/db/PICTURES/CMS/270600/270602.2.jpg'}
```

Comment: Thank's for correcting my mistake and detail explanation,  I wanted to output in dictionary format, so I'm choosing another answer. I liked your approach.

Comment: Actually, this is a dictionary, I just printed the items individually :) But it's fine that you selected the other answer. Select the answer that solves your question with the most accuracy.

Comment: `.items()` is a method for a dictionary. Have a look at [Looping Techniques for dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) if you weren't aware of that.

Comment: How can I embed image link along with that article link, so I can show an image of that post when I render on webpage?

Comment: Add that in the question, or create a new question and I'll edit my answer and add that part.

Comment: I edited the question, how can I do that? when I extract that link I want to see the preview of image

Comment: Do you want help extracting the image link or previewing that image? For previewing it, the easiest way is to use `webbrowser.open('use-image-link-here)`.

Comment: Check the edit. I've added the code that you can use to get the image with the other info you wanted.

Comment: I wanted those to be callable link, so whenever I press that link it will take to that respective website page, 'Nylon Calculus Week 15 in Review: Injuries, mythology and Steven Adams': 'https://fansided.com/2018/01/30/nylon-calculus-injuries-mythology-steven-adams/', this is complete link, how can I do this?

Comment: I think it's becoming a bit out of scope and 'too broad' for this question. Ask a new question for the second part. I don't think `web-scraping` and the second question are related.

Comment: yeah understand, 2nd part is can't be done, how can I change first part so I call that link as this Nylon Calculus: Game Control and a new take on team metrics': 'https://fansided.com/2018/01/30/nylon-calculus-game-control-score/',

Comment: Your original question has been answered. I'm sorry to say this but, SO is not a code writing service. Do some research, and if you think you are not able to do that, ask a **new** question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).